# Using unix script to read delimiter file and load in DB

Tags: unix

I'm trying to extract tar file which has .txt file, Then read .txt file delimited with | and load the same into Oracle DB. I'm able to untar the file but when it reaches to "do /home/uid/test/dataTest.sql". It says as cannot execute.

Any way to read .txt file delimited with "|" and load it to oracle DB without using sqlldr??

Is "Load data infile" can be used in Oracle directly as like MySQL without using sqlldr??

```
**//testScript.sh**
tar -xvf test.tar
[ -f "/home/uid/test/ref.txt" ] && echo "File present" || exit 1
while read line
do
/home/uid/test/dataTest.sql
done < /home/uid/test/ref.txt
##Here connect the DB to insert 
sqlldr -s username/pwd@//hostname:portNumb <<EOF
set scan off;
@/home/uid/test/dataTest.sql
exit;
EOF

**//dataTest.sql**
load data
infile '/home/uid/test/ref.txt'
into table STAGE1
fields terminated by "|"
( NAME, NUMB, FILENAME );

 **//ref.txt** 
 Suraj R Krishna, SF|1234598|2015FEB_Suraj R Krishna, SF(xxxxx4598)
 Krish S Sampson, TE, SRFT|1234934|2015FEB_Krish S Sampson, TE, SRFT          
 (xxxxx4934)
```

Any of your help is appreciated!
Thanks!

Comment: `dataTest.sql` must be a script or program. Having the `.sql` extension makes be belive it is an sql script, not a shell script. What is inside? If a shell scdript, then edit your question to include output of `ls -l /home/uid/test/dataTest.sql` .Also check each dir in that path that the userID running the script has premission to access each level of the p`/home/uid/test`. What is  your need for "load it to oracle DB without using sqlldr"? Short of writing a `c` program, you'll have to use `sqlldr`. Just install and fix it! ;-)  Good luck.

Comment: @shellter: Thankyou! shelter.I don't have sqlldr installed then will install sql loader and check for the same. dataTest.sql has                                 "load data
infile '/home/uid/test/ref.txt'
into table STAGE1
fields terminated by "|"
( NAME, NUMB, FILENAME );"

Answer (score 1):

remove while read line
do
/home/uid/test/dataTest.sql
done < /home/uid/test/ref.txt
with

> `sqlldr ${USERNAME}/${PASSWORD}@${DATABASENAME} SILENT=HEADER,FEEDBACK control=/home/uid/test/dataTest.sql LOG=<name>`

/home/uid/test/dataTest.sql looks like a Control file.